# Fragment onAttach() method crash my Code

Tags: android, fragment

This onAttach method crash my android application, I want to know the relevance of this method and what will happen if I remove the method completely

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

I removed it and my code runs smoothly hope it wont lead to any problem in the future.

Comment: You should specify the line of code giving error and share the error as well.

Comment: If `context` is not instance of `OnFragmentInteractionListener`, you are throwing exception. It could be the reason of crash.

Answer (score 1):

Here is problem `context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener`

[**Fragment comunication Android docs.**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is the [documentation's way](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for working with fragments in activity, when a communication is needed between the two. I mention that it's the documentation's way because it's not the only way (you could use other techniques such as publish/subscribe engines e.g. [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)).

This code intentionally throws a RunTimeException if the activity the fragment was attached to does not implement the interface the fragment expects to be attached to. If it does implement it - the activity is saved as a pointer of that interface type (in your case - `OnFragmentInteractionListener`).

You can see the line throwing the exception:

```
throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
            + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
```

so if you have in the console " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener" - you know the fragment was attached to the  activity which should implement OnFragmentInteractionListener but doesn't.